# Fold function in Octave

Tags: functional-programming, octave, reduce, fold

Is there standard implementation of fold (reduce, aggregate etc) for one dimensional vector in Octave?
If no, is there any way to express fold without using a loop statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`miscellaneous`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/miscellaneous/index.html) package provides the function [`reduce`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/miscellaneous/function/reduce.html).  For example,

```
octave:6> reduce(@(x,y)(x*y), [1:5])
ans =  120
```

If you look at the source code for `reduce`, you'll see that it is a fairly simple Octave function that is implemented with a `for` loop, so it won't be more efficient than implementing the reduction with a `for` loop of your own.

Comment: I actually can't use any outside packages for Machine Learning class, so I wrote my own reduce function, I just love in FP languages and missing the clarity they brought to my mind and my code :)