# Octave/Matlab vectorization of for-loop with function

Tags: matlab, function, octave, vectorization

I have a function that has a vector as input and I want to apply a function to each element with the output of the previous step. I have implemented a for-loop:

```
function res = myFunc(F)
if (numel(F) == 1)
    res = F(1);
    return;
end;
B = F(1);
for idx = 2:numel(F)
    B = procAcc(F(idx),B);
res = B;    
end
```

The function procAcc takes two parameters and produces an output. That is, if the input is a vector (f1, f2, f3), I apply first the function procAcc(f1,f2), it produces a result (res) and in the next step I apply the function procAcc (a3,res) that produces the final result. My question is if Matlab (or Octave) support a vectorized approach that would allow me to skip the for-loop.

Comment: You need to vectorize `procAcc`, not `myFunc`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "vectorization" in this case, as calculation of element `i` depends on element `i-1`. Your calculations have to be chained. Instead try using a functional approach - "mapreduce" is a powerful concept and is applicable in variety of cases. There doesn't seem to be a native function in Octave, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22920799/1405399) answer references a package that provides a `reduce` function. If you use it, the `for` loop should be replaced by something like this:

```
res = reduce(@(x,y)(procAcc(x,y)), F);
```

Commonly mapreduce provides some performance benefits over a `for` loop, but in the current case that will depend on the implementation of the package that provides the `reduce` function.